# CSS Target 2nd td on the first 3 rows only

Tags: css

Okay so i got a really specific css i need to set for the first 3 rows and only on the 2nd td of those 3 rows. is there anyway to target only them in css rules?

right now i am trying like this

here is the render

```
  <tr className={getRowColor(props, l, i)}>
                                <td>{i + 1}</td>
                                <td className="info-table-cell{l.info}</td>
                            </tr>
```

and here it is the second td in this row that i want to target for the first 3 rows only. And right now i try like this

```
.info-table-cell td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #FFF45E;
}

.info-table-cell td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.info-table-cell td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #FFC933;
}
```

but that does nothing. Anyone who knows how to do this?

Comment: Right now, you are targeting the table _cells_, that are the first, second or third child of their parent. If you want to target _rows_ that are the x-th child of their parent, then that obviously starts with `tr:nth-child`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps you. I have added a red background color for nd td of first 3 rows. Try it:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2),
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2),
table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>  
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>4</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>  
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>4</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>  
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>4</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>  
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>4</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>  
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>4</td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>  
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>  
    <td>4</td>  
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: exactly what i were looking for! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

If i understand you correcly, its indeed possible. There are some problem with your code, your not selecting anything because info-table-cell is the td. Here is my approach:

**Html**

```
<table class="your-specific-class">
  <tr>
    <td class="info-table-cell">Content 1</td>
    <td class="info-table-cell">Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="info-table-cell">Content 1</td>
    <td class="info-table-cell">Content 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="info-table-cell">Content 1</td>
    <td class="info-table-cell">Content 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.your-specific-class tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #FFF45E;
}
.your-specific-class tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.your-specific-class tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #FFC933;
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/lauritzz77/pen/XoLjXr